# why I am getting an error while launching eclipse in headless mode for building rule app using automation tool plugin

Tags: eclipse, build-automation, ibm-odm

[eclipse error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXiNs.png) I was trying to do eclipse headless build (build rule app) from the command prompt with the below code.

```
plugin- (ilog.rules.studio.automation.builder)
```

Plugin came with odm instalation files.

I am seeing an error in cmd that
`-perspectiv` is not a valid option.
Importing a list of projects into a workspace applies an extension model and builds them to generate ruleset archives.

> eclipsec -application ilog.rules.studio.automation.builder -noSplash -nl en_US -importPath "C:\Ashaspace\tutorial\Miniloan\miniloan-xom;C:\Ashaspace\tutorial\Miniloan\MiniloanService" MiniloanService?MiniloanServiceOperation -cleanBuild -buildOptions BUILD_CHECK_IRL MiniloanService

I am following steps from [ibm-odm knowledge center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS7J8H/com.ibm.odm.dserver.rules.designer.run/build_topics/tpc_buildautotool.html)

Can anyone help me what is this error and how to fix it?

Comment: Can you run Eclipse non-headless? Which Eclipse and Java version do you have?

Comment: Thanks for responding!! The issue is not java version.

Answer (score 1):

```
-perspective
ilog.rules.studio.ui.perspectives.RuleEditingPerspective
```

Removing this line from eclipse.ini file will help to resolve the issue.